# Git Remote Access

Tags: git, git-server

I'm currently working on a solution where I intend to view and edit a remote git repository existent on my server machine.

I'm wondering if it is possible to gain access to that remote repository without checking out/cloning the repository itself locally.

I would like to have the possibility to commit and push files to the remote repository just by running git commands. Is this possible, or there's no way for this to work?

**Note**: I also notice that with GitHub, VS Code already has an extension that allows to open and edit/commit files to the remote repository without having to clone it. I would like to do a similar thing, but on my own, since I'm using GitBlit as my remote git server.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, but you want to edit files without cloning the project? If that's the case, some web interfaces (like Github) allows you to edit and commit files within the browser (not need to clone the project).

Comment: Basically, what I'm wondering is if by having a remote repository on my remote machine running using GitBlit, I can access through my local machine to that repository and edit the files, as the GitHub Repositories VS Code extension does.

Comment: These are features of the hosting services. If Gitblit does not have such features, you need to clone the repositories.

Comment: Git is specifically designed the *opposite* way: so that all work is *local*. You can get around this, but only by having the Git-like work done remotely, or by implementing something that acts like Git but fakes it (which will perform really terribly).